# Create common connect class

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and need help with creating a class, which can be called in every newly created class and return connection to database. There is what  I have done so far:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SqlQueries
{
    class DBConnect
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            //Initialize();
        }

        private  static MySqlConnection connection;
        private  static string server;
        private  static string database;
        private  static string uid;
        private  static string password;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            server = "testing.com";
            database = "mus_le";
            uid = "muff";
            password = "test";

            string connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";"+"Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";";

            using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        public void Select(string query)
        {
            DBConnect QConnect = new DBConnect();
            // Here I want to call this class somewhere and pass
            // query string to it and return result from select stmt
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(QConnect.Initialize(),query);
            // here I get error Unable to convert void to string...
        }
    }
}
```

I am searching and reading from 2 days now, and there is nowhere solution to this problem, I am wondering what to do.Would be really really thankful  if somebody of you guys give me books or something to read,and learn c# from.

Comment: Where comes from DBConnect class?

Comment: Why do you have to write this from scratch? Such a connection kind of object while coming be found on most db access libraries already.

Comment: @DavelnCaz I want to learn the lang. And I think that is the way to learn something, start from scratch.(Also I don't know what are those libs, where to find them and how to use them,lol)

Comment: @miechooy I don't undestand the question, sorry .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, the MySqlCommand constructor takes a MySqlConnection and a string query as arguments but your DBConnect.Initialize method is void.

The second issue is that the connection is disposed as soon as it leaves the using statement in the Initialize method which means you can't reuse it (if that is what you trying to do..)

```
using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

What you can do instead is to return the connection from initialize and wrap your db operation in a using statement in the calling method

Update the DBConnect Initialize method to return the MySqlConnection instance

```
public static MySqlConnection Initialize()
{
    server = "testing.com";
    database = "mus_le";
    uid = "muff";
    password = "test";

    string connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";"+"Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";";
    return new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Then use it

```
public void Select(string query)
{
    using (var connection = DBConnect.Initialize())
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(connection,query))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, do you have any suggestions for books, to learn C# faster :?

Comment: Np :), I think this book is really great https://www.amazon.com/C-7-0-Nutshell-Definitive-Reference/dp/1491987650

Answer (score 3):

Your method `Initialize` returns `void`, it should return the connection instead :

```
public static MySqlConnection Initialize()
{
    server = "testing.com";
    database = "mus_le";
    uid = "muff";
    password = "test";

    string connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";"+"Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";";

    return new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
}
```

and then you would use it like this :

```
public class Query
{
    public void Select(string query)
    {
        DBConnect QConnect = new DBConnect();
        // Here I want to call this class somewhere and pass
        // query string to it and return result from select stmt
        using (MySqlConnection conn = QConnect.Initialize())
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(conn,query);
        }
    }
}
```

But as the comments say, these objects are usually provided...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse your class you can simply create is a base class for any others. Every newly created class can inherit from the base and have an access to database without reusing the code. There is a base method for Select(). You can add also any other SQL operation there.

```
  public class DbContext
    {
        private static MySqlConnection connection;
        private static string server;
        private static string database;
        private static string uid;
        private static string password;

        private static string ConnectionString = "Server=" + server + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";";

        static DbContext()
        {
            server = "testing.com";
            database = "mus_le";
            uid = "muff";
            password = "test";
        }

        protected object Select(string query)
        {
            using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                DBConnect QConnect = new DBConnect();
                // Here I want to call this class somewhere and pass
                // query string to it and return result from select stmt
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(QConnect.Initialize(), query);
                // here I get error Unable to convert void to string...

                //return result
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeNewReader : DbContext
    {
        public object SelectSomething()
        {
            return base.Select("some query");
        }
    }


    public class SomeNewReader1 : DbContext
    {
        public object SelectSomething()
        {
            return base.Select("some query");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question for books and something to read.

You should always look at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2), often there are good examples that explain how these classes are used, additionally search for keywords on google or [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com) like listed below in combination with C# oder .NET

- Data access layer (DAL)
- Data access object (DAO)

Further, you can improve your skills with reading something about OOP design patterns [Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software - Erich Gamma et al.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

- e.g. Factory Pattern - should be used to create a specific database from an abstraction

In the modern OOP frameworks today, you will find implementations with using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to decouple infrastructure code (e.g. your database and sql-statements) from business logic (e.g. specific operations on data).

For the csharp-language itself they are literally available as the sand of the sea. It depends on your OOP and programming skills which one fits for you. [Professional C# 7 and .NET Core](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/category/csharp/)